# Is there any widget that IDLE python ide uses for its code autocomplete feature?

Tags: python, autocomplete, python-idle

With which widget does IDLE, show a dropdown for autocomplete feature which contains a list of classes, methods, functions, etc. Please view the picture [from this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbE8r.jpg) for reference.

Comment: Probably a dropdown.

Comment: but how does it change its position (coordinates) according to the movement of the keyboard cursor?

Answer (score 2):

IDLE currently uses a `tkinter.Listbox`.  It is combined with a Scrollbar in a Frame.  The up and down keys are bound event handlers.  The code is not the best but you can view it in `.../Lib/idlelib/autcomplete_w.py`.